# VMware vCenter Server 5.5 Single Sign-On Install finds wrong ip address for FQDN

Tags: vmware, esxi

I am migrating my vCenter Server 5.5 to a new server (databases have already been moved to a new SQL server and all is OK on existing vCenter Server 5.5 implementation). When I begin the simple install process on the new vCenter Server host the Single Sign-On component presents me with an IP address of 10.10.10.117 as the ip address of the FQDN file01.xxxxxxxxx.com. This is the iSCSI interface address. I need it to use the 10.1.1.17 ip address that is the address of the production NIC that the ESXi 5.5 hosts will be communicating with. I have already changed the binding order of the NIC cards and flushed the DNS cache. I also added file01.xxxxxxxx.com with the proper IP address to the hosts file and also file01 to the hosts file. Still, during the install, 10.10.10.117 is discovered. Thanks in advance! Babak C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get a quick clarification...are you freshly installing vCenter 5.5?  Or are you migrating an existing vCenter server to a new host and using the update utility to upgrade?  I am assuming you are doing a fresh install based on your details about the SQL server and SSO.  Here is my suggestion, in case it is a fresh install.

We had a similar problem with 5.5 on a new install where the IP address that was discovered during the actual vCenter Server install was that of the public facing NIC which we never use for management traffic (it's for internet access on the vC server, for update manager, etc.)

The strange thing is that there had NEVER been an entry in ANY of our DNS servers for that interface.  So, after looking into it a little bit, I started thinking the IP that was returned during install was not a DNS result at all.  Rather, it was (most likely) simply gathered from the interfaces on the Server based on binding order (e.g. which NIC has the default gateway.)

In order to save having to uninstall and clean up a major mess if the install completed wrong, we stopped and got in touch with VMware support.  They suggested we clear all of the temporary files both in the standard "temporary" folder on windows as well as under /ApplicationData/vmware/xxx, where 'xxx' would be whatever product is giving you trouble and ***HAS NOT been FULLY INSTALLED**** (e.g. you started the install and noticed the incorrect IP, so you terminated the installer and there is metadata and cached files remaining from the partially run install).

Basically, what we had to do, was clear the temporary files and then make sure the NIC Binding Priority was correct (so you should check in Network Adapters|(press-alt)|Advanced Settings.  Make sure the correct binding is checked (e.g. if you don't use IPv6 on the private network, clear it) and make sure that the Windows Network is at the top of the priority list on the second pane of the advanced settings.  This helps tremendously with SSO by making sure the Windows Network stack is the first queried when you are signing in and SSO must submit a kerberos ticket to the AD DC for validation.

It is possible, that once you delete the partial install files and temporary files and fix the network settings (probably be a good idea to reboot as well), the next time you run the installer you might have success.

I will try to check this post later to see if it helped you at all... or it I just succeeded in making your life even more difficult (which I certainly hope not!) :)

One more thing...prior to initializing the installer, open up a PS session, perform ipconfig /flushdns and then ping the hostname of your vCenter server in order to get it in the DNS cache.  You should also perform the following:

nslookup

NS>{your vcenter server IP address}

/* make sure the resulting hostname is correct..this ensures your PTRs and rDNS is working correctly.  vCenter HEAVILY relies on accurate reverse DNS configuration...then do the following lookup for forward DNS */

NS>{your vcenter server FQDN}

Hope it helps.  Best of luck my friend!

SIETEC